# Magento custom save order

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

We have a custom discount option other than magento default discount/coupon option. In that customer can choose the full amount to be paid from their balance amount with the account.

So if they choose to pay the total amount then i want to skip the magento payment tab. In the custom action i have to save the order and redirect the checkout page customer to checkout success page. How can i do that. When i call order->save(), it throws error like " Should select a payment option."

Please help me to skip the payment option on checkout page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than skipping that option entirely, creating a new payment type to pay from the account would probably be clearer to the customer. You could preselect that option for the customer, and keep the rest of the system intact.

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: Yes, am left with no other option. I will have to do this only. Thanks